# replacing home appliances' internal 120v to 220v

Tags: voltage, appliances

stackexchange,

am new to electronics but am fairly resourceful. am asking this question out of curiosity. i have 2 home appliances which I bought in US.

1. A [Sunbeam hot shot (hot water) dispenser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000C3QSPQ) which runs on 120v 1450w 60hz
2. A [Hamilton beach blender](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002V8ZEXW) which runs on 120v 175w

I currently live in Bangalore, India. These appliances have been lying unused with me since 2 years and I would want to use these appliances. Selling them off is not an option. Also I don't want to buy a bulking step down converter as it looks ugly on my kitchen counter space.

I read an [article on ebay about replacing the internal circuit breaker](http://www.ebay.com/gds/How-to-Convert-120V-to-220V-/10000000205290556/g.html).

Is this possible on the appliances mentioned above? If so do you think an electrician here would have the knowledge of doing such a procedure? What parts, equipments would I need for such a procedure?

Thank you.

**Update**

I was of the impression there might not be buyers for US bought electrical appliances in India but am guessing since its October (the month of immigrants from India to US on H1B) I have had quite a few people approach me to buy those things I listed.

From reading the immediate comments to my question, am guessing I misunderstood the ebay post and that converting a home appliance from its default voltage by modifying it internally may not be possible as a DIY or even industrially.

Comment: The article you linked to on ebay is about setting up a 220VAC outlet in a home that has 110VAC.  I wouldn't do what they describe, because they are putting 220VAC on an outlet made for 110VAC.  Madness, and a disaster wating to happen when you accidentally plug a 110VAC device into that 110VAC outlet that actually provides 220VAC.

Comment: There are converters that can be use with both devices to make 110VAC from 220VAC.  They will probably work well with the hot water heater, but not so well with the blender.  These devices are small boxes that have a 220VAC plug on one side and a 110VAC outlet on the other.  They are smaller than a transformer. [Like this one](https://www.amazon.com/International-Voltage-Converter-appliances-overseas/dp/B000WQ0MTG)

Comment: @JRE 'for short time use only!'. Let's assume it *is* a switch mode voltage converter, there's not much room for filtering in there. If it's more like a lighting dimmer set to 50%, that's going to put an interesting power factor on the line.

Comment: They are not switching anything.  The cheap ones (as linked to) usually just have a half wave rectifier.  I wouldn't use one long term either, but they are one of the (few) options available that doesn't involve a transformer.  There are switching units available that make 110VAC from 220VAC.  They cost more, and I don't know how much power they are rated for nor what they will do to the power factor.

Comment: _"Selling them off is not an option."_ - I beg to differ. Not only is it an option, it's likely your _best_ option.

Comment: @marcelm: Selling then shipping them to someplace where they can be used (to the US from India) is likely to be more hassle and cost more than just tossing the things out as junk and buying a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

There's one trick I know which works for some very simple, resistive load only appliances with high thermal mass. One can use diodes to cut the power in half, making *some* 120V devices happily accept 240V. For example, I had this 120V toaster which worked quite well in Europe:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcBfB9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are many gotchas with this approach, and it's probably doomed if your device has anything else than resistors (motors, electrical timers, LCDs and so on). I wouldn't recommend it if you don't have the full picture of how your device works.

Comment: [That's what those things do that I linked to.](https://www.amazon.com/International-Voltage-Converter-appliances-overseas/dp/B000WQ0MTG)  Nothing but a halfwave rectifier in a box with a plug and an outlet.

Comment: @JRE Sorry, I missed your link. Also, I'm a bit surprised they sell such stuff as a consumer product.

Comment: They've been around since at least the early 1980's.  That's when I first saw them in the electronics shops in the US.  Mostly intended for using US hair (blow) dryers in Europe.

Comment: Powering an AC motor from half-bridge rectifier output sounds dodgy. Like you said, "not so well with the blender"...

Comment: This is not an ideal solution (the single diode option is also uncertain).  The power output is going to be double.  The voltage is double, the current will be doubled, the power is squared and then halved because only one element is working at a time.  You may easily find that the peak current (which is double) will exceed the safe current of the device before long even if average is the same the power generated will heat it twice as fast/hot.

Comment: @KalleMP I have never seen resistors damaged by peak current, nor have I ever seen a resistor datasheet with specific peak current rating. And no human-scale resistor (meaning dimensions in mm and up) will overheat from double current in 10ms.

Comment: @KalleMP is right about the power.  You're putting 170 Vrms across each element in the 2 diode scheme.  Might not damage your toaster immediately, but it should shorten its life.  On the plus side, though, you spend less time waiting for it to pop.